# .net Naming convention: Is there a semantic difference between Length and Count?

Tags: .net

In order to to get the number of subitems in dotnet sometimes i have to ask a property Lenght sometimes i have to ask a property Count.

Is there any reason for the distinction?

example:

```
   int[] a; if (a.Length == 0) ....
   IList<int> b; if (b.Count == 0) ....
```

Note [Difference between IEnumerable Count() and Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521592/difference-between-ienumerable-count-and-length) sounds similar but does not answer the semantic between Length and Count

Comment: see this in fact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no semantic difference. It just a framework design detail that we should deal with.

Answer (score 5):

I can't quote a source, but I think that a .Length is a fixed value and a .Count can change.

You can't change the number of items in an array once it is created, so that has a .Length.

You *can* add to (or remove from) a `List`, so that has a .Count.

**EDIT**
So a `.Length`:

- Will not change for this object
- Should involve just a quick lookup of an internal value

While a `.Count` or `.Count()`:

- Might change for this object
- Might involve an iteration over the internal items (depending on the implementation)

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Same applies to string.Length since the string cannot be changed. The Stringbuilder is mutable but it has Length property

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, an array has a constant number of elements, it has a *length*, therefore the property is called Length. A list has variable number of elements, and if you want to know how many elements are there, you need to *count* them, therefore the Count name.

Answer (score 2):

`Length` is an array property, `Count` an `ICollection` one and `Count()` a method on `IEnumerable`, but aside from that, they mean the same.

That is, they hold that number of items in the collection.

Note: in the case of `IEnumerable`, the `Count()` method can (and normally will) iterate over all items in the collection in order to obtain a count. The properties will simply return a value.

Comment: Count is not a *property* of IEnumerable, it's a method there.

Comment: @Hans - I was thinking about `IList`

Comment: Count is inherited by IList from ICollection

Comment: I think when calling Count() on IEnumerable it checks the underlying type i.e. checks if its a List so it can use Count property before iterating over the items to count them.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756) contains an annotation about this difference (I will at a qoute of it tomorrow). What I recall is that the designers think this is a quirk in the design, because it doesn't make sense for a lot of developers. Remember that in the beginning there were no design guidelines for .NET and much of the .NET API was copied from Java, including the quirks.