# What's the difference between String.Count and String.Length?

Tags: c#, string, count

I'm using them alternately. Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Related: *[Difference between IEnumerable Count() and Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521592/difference-between-ienumerable-count-and-length)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the surface they would seem functionally identical, but the main difference is:

- `Length` is a property that is defined of strings and is the usual way to find the length of a string
- `.Count()` is implemented as an extension method. That is, what `string.Count()` really does is call [`Enumerable.Count(this IEnumerable<char>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx), a `System.Linq` extension method, given that `string` is really a sequence of `char`s.

Performance concerns of LINQ enumerable methods notwithstanding, use `Length` instead, as it's built right into strings.

Answer (score 2):

String implements the `IEnumerable`, so it has a method `Count` while `Length` is a property in the String class.

Answer (score 2):

`String.Length` is the "correct" property to use. `String.Count()` is just an `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` implementation and could be slower.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about the speed difference between Count and Length.  I believed Length would be faster ...

I created a simple script in [LINQPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) to test this:

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

string SomeText = @"";

bool DoLength = true;
//DoLength = false;

if (DoLength)  //1252
{
    timer.Start();
    SomeText.Length.Dump("Length");
    timer.Stop();
    timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("Elapsed");
}
else  //1166
{
    timer.Start();
    SomeText.Count().Dump("Count");
    timer.Stop();
    timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("Elapsed");
}
```

I added a long string of text to test this in SomeText.  I noted that I had to do them in separate runs to get more accurate results for the second test. Running in tandem always resulted in a faster response on the second call. (Removing the comment for DoLength will run the count test).

I put my results in comments next to the if or else.  I was surprised that Count turned out to be faster than Length.

Feel free to do your own tests.

Comment: I think more tests would be needed, on this blog, the author got a clear difference between both https://programminghave.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-count-or-length.html