# Does calling Count on IEnumerable iterate the whole collection?

Tags: c#, performance, count, ienumerable

Consider the following code:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetItems()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToArray();  // or: .ToList();
}

static void Main()
{
    int count = GetItems().Count();
}
```

Will it iterate over all the 10 billion integers and count them one-by-one, or will it use the array's `Length` / list's `Count` properties?

Comment: No, `Length` (in case of array) or `Count` (in case of `IList<T>`) will be used

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521592/difference-between-ienumerable-count-and-length

Comment: You can find the implementation yourself :) http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b

Comment: I will also recommand to use LongCount if you expect the result to be bigger than Int32

Comment: Hope you're alright with the duplicate closure. It's not a 100% duplicate but the question is answered there (and more).

Comment: It is quite hard to create an array that has more than `int.MaxValue` items @GuillaumeBeauvois

Comment: always use Length if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `IEnumerable` is an `ICollection`, it will return the `Count` property.

Here's the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b):

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        checked
        {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

An array implements `ICollection<T>`, so it doesn't need to be enumerated.

Comment: So, does the code given return an `ICollection` or not?

Comment: @PatrickHofman *Which* code?

Comment: `return Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToArray();  // or: .ToList();`, as in the question.

Comment: As discussed here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482567/3150802), arrays implement `IList<T>` which in turn is an `ICollection<T>`. These implementations are added at run time giving arrays a special status, but they are there, so yes, calling `.Count()` on a an array should be a O(1) operation, no matter what type the reference has.

Comment: That would make the answer actually answer the question @Peter.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Right, I edited the answer.

Comment: I see, I updated it a little to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The code will first put all the integers into array (due to your `.ToArray()` call), and then return the length of the array (since [all arrays implement `ICollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482567/)), which the actual code calls. It will not count all items in the array one by one.

Comment: I cannot detect an array in the source code presented by @Jakub, and I don't see a reason why one should create one.

Comment: @PeterSchneider There is in the code from OP, just read: `return Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToArray(); ` The code clearly calls `ToArray`.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood. Well. I guess the answer to the OP is "you just did something insane but the compiler will not add insanity on top". I assume that C# compilers are allowed to apply the as-if rule, so the compiler is allowed to do nothing at all (since the program has no observable effect). If you print the count, the compiler is free to just print 10000000, no arrays or anything.

Comment: No, since it doesn't know there aren't side effects. It will create the array, no matter how useless it is.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You can see there are no side effects; I can see it. The compiler can see it. It's all there, in plain view. The complete source code is even in a single translation unit. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, compilers are dumb @Peter.