# Errors with the TypeInfo class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

Okay I keep getting error that .Length isn't in Enumerable. Can someone edit it to make it right? thanks!!

```
 public void StartAnimation(GameObject _gameObject)
{
    TypeInfo mytype = typeof(iTweenAnimation).GetTypeInfo();
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> myFields = mytype.DeclaredFields ;
    Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
    for (int i = 0; i < myFields.Length; i++)
    {
        hash.Add(myFields[i].Name, myFields[i].GetValue(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Count(). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521592/difference-between-ienumerable-count-and-length) SO question.

Comment: You'll want to use `foreach()` instead of `for()` here. This avoids the issue of `Length` entirely - and will prevent your next error: being unable to reference an item via its index

Comment: example plz thanks!

Comment: You could try `foreach (var field in myFields)  { hash.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(this)); }` as @Rob suggested.

Comment: Thanks! it works